# How to verify data is loaded into mongodb after load generation phase in ycsb?

Tags: performance, mongodb, benchmarking, ycsb

I am trying to use ycsb to carry out benchmarking of mongodb.

I have downloaded and installed mongo db as per instructions specified on [YCSB MongoDB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/tree/master/mongodb)

After that I created "ycsb" named database in mongodb using below commands

```
1. use ycsb 
2. db.createCollection("ycsb")
```

As specified in above link, I ran below command to load data into ycsb DB,

```
./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 -p mongodb.database=ycsb
```

I just wanted to check load phase execution so I have not specified other parameters. I got below log on screen,

```
root@pegdb2:~/ycsb-0.1.4# ./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 -p mongodb.database=ycsb
java -cp /root/ycsb-0.1.4/gemfire-binding/conf:/root/ycsb-0.1.4/infinispan-binding/conf:/root/ycsb-0.1.4/nosqldb-binding/conf:/root/ycsb-0.1.4/core/lib/core-0.1.4.jar:/root/ycsb-0.1.4/hbase-binding/conf:/root/ycsb-0.1.4/mongodb-binding/lib/mongodb-binding-0.1.4.jar:/root/ycsb-0.1.4/voldemort-binding/conf:/root/ycsb-0.1.4/jdbc-binding/conf com.yahoo.ycsb.Client -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 -p mongodb.database=ycsb -load
YCSB Client 0.1
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 -p mongodb.database=ycsb -load
Loading workload...
Starting test.
new database url = 127.0.0.1:27017/ycsb
 0 sec: 0 operations;
mongo connection created with 127.0.0.1:27017/ycsb
java.lang.NullPointerException
 0 sec: 0 operations; [INSERT AverageLatency(us)=28568]
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 143.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 0.0
[INSERT], Operations, 1
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 28568.0
[INSERT], MinLatency(us), 28568
[INSERT], MaxLatency(us), 28568
[INSERT], 95thPercentileLatency(ms), 28
[INSERT], 99thPercentileLatency(ms), 28
[INSERT], Return=1, 1
[INSERT], 0, 0
[INSERT], 1, 0
[INSERT], 2, 0
[INSERT], 3, 0
[INSERT], 4, 0
[INSERT], 5, 0
[INSERT], 6, 0
[INSERT], 7, 0
[INSERT], 8, 0
[INSERT], 9, 0
[INSERT], 10, 0
    .
    .
[INSERT], 999, 0
[INSERT], >1000, 0
```

After this step I just wanted to check whether is loaded successfully in DB or not. I checked using,

```
1. use ycsb
2. db.ycsb.find()
```

but search results were 0. It might be a very easy question but it will be helpful if someone provides me the correct way to load and verify the data in DB.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You could verify if the command actually loads the data into a collection named `ycsb`, or some other collection, by going through the command parameter docs.

Comment: yes. As I have mentioned in question, I tried finding in collection named ycsb in db ycsb using db.ycsb.find() command. but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: The logs say that there is a `java.lang.NullPointerException` Exception while loading, can you make it more verbose?

Comment: I don't know how to make it verbose. Can you provide me the command?

Comment: https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload - Please see if this helps in identifying the tables that need to be looked into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with one required parameter which I had not specified while loading the data.

mongodb.writeConcern is the parameter required while loading the data and running the workload. It should have one of following value,

```
-p mongodb.writeConcern=none
-p mongodb.writeConcern=strict
-p mongodb.writeConcern=normal
```

Generally `-p mongodb.writeConcern=strict` works as it keeps session open and consistent. This also stops getting NPE errors.

After loading the data in MongoDB, data can be verified in `usertable` table/collection using `db.usertable.find()` or `db.usertable.count()` commands.